# how to get fullpath to latest file via Directoryinfo

Tags: c#, getfiles, directoryinfo

I'm trying to locate the latest .XML file in the latest created folder. I guess it's a simple solution, but for me as a newbie, it makes my hair turn grey.

My Code:

```
    string dir = runfrom + @"\results";
    string xml = "*.xml";
    DirectoryInfo newestdir = new DirectoryInfo(dir).GetDirectories().OrderByDescending(d => d.LastWriteTimeUtc).First();
    var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(newestdir.ToString());
    var file = (from f in dirInfo.GetFiles(xml) orderby f.LastWriteTime descending select f).First();
```

*dirinfo* only contains the newest directory's name, but not full path. I (of course) get an error, because the directory is not found without it's path.

Comment: this doesnt seem like you tried, so you have a runfrom which is a path, you then get newestdir, which is filenames in that folder.. so runfrom+newestdir+file? let alone look at directoryinfo options

Comment: _newestdir_ is a folder, not file. If I build up a string, I cannot use getfiles on it. I already tried that

Comment: no but when you want to use the file name ........ you have the option to use directoryinfo to pull the full name of newestdir, or chain runfrom+newesdir+file....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DirectoryInfo.FullName` to get the full path.

> **FullName** -     Gets the full path of the directory or file.(Inherited from
>   FileSystemInfo.)

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

---

However, seems you don't need to get the full path - you can use the `DirectoryInfo` instance to enumerate it's files.

```
DirectoryInfo newestdir = new DirectoryInfo(dir).GetDirectories().OrderByDescending(d => d.LastWriteTimeUtc).First();
var file = (from f in newestdir.GetFiles(xml) orderby f.LastWriteTime descending select f).First();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you very much!
Now I can build the full string with
string full = dir + @"\" + newestdir.ToString() + @"\" + file.ToString();